# Making user defined Map

Tags: java

I have a pojo named Employee, now I want to make a user defined collection that I want to put on a map. Please advise me how to achieve this.

```
public class Employee {
    String name,job;
    int salary;

    public Employee(String n , String j, int t) {
        this.name= n;
        this.job=j;
        this.salary= t;          
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {      
        return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {  
        Employee e = (Employee) obj;    
        return this.name.equals(e.name) && this.job.equals(e.job)
                   && this.salary == e.salary;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just for reference take a look at items 7 and 8 [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) for implementing equals and hashcode

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for.  If you want to associate Employees with a key (say, their name), you could do:

```
Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
```

If you want to map Employees to some other value, you can do:

```
Map<Employee, MyOtherType> employeeMap = new HashMap<Employee, MyOtherType>();
```

Comment: I want to store employees in map...something like this..Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, Employee>();              
employeeMap.put(a, "Saral","Trainer","34000"); please advise me how to achieve this..!!!!

Comment: @user1334074 Lots of exclamation marks may be seen as rude. Please ask nicely

Comment: Employee e = new Employee("Saral", "Trainer", 34000); employeeMap.put(e.getName(), e);

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following: (?)

```
Collection<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<Employee>();
Map<String, Collection<Employee>> map = new HashMap<String, Collection<Employee>>();

...........

//Now fill the map as following:
List<Employee> employeesOfTheDepartment = new LinkedList<Employee>();
employeesOfTheDepartment.add(employee);
map.put(employee.getDepartment(), employeesOfTheDepartment);
```

Comment: I want to store employees in map...something like this..Map<String, Employee> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, Employee>(); employeeMap.put(a, "Saral","Trainer","34000"); please advise me how to achieve this..!!!